# How does my ipcamera work despite UPnP disabled on home router?

Tags: iot, port-forwarding, upnp

Recently I bought an IPcamera in order to test its security. Unfortunately, it just has 2 ports open :

- 554/tcp RTSP
- 5000/tcp UPnP

I was pretty sure the ipcamera would poke my router and open up internet facing port (that's what UPnP is suppose to do, right?) through which I can test further but unfortunately that is not the case.

My home router (D-Link) has UPnP disabled by default. I explicitly enabled UPnP on the router to test for open ports but ipcam is not opening any port facing internet.

> Question:

- If ipcam is not opening internet facing port then what is UPnP used for in the ipcam ?
- Why is ipcam not opening external port even after UPnp enabled in router?

Comment: UPnP is not just for opening ports. It is also used for device discovery; i.e. so devices can find each other on the network without specifically being configured to talk. Also, a UPnP client would be the one requesting ports opened, not a server on the device. Maybe it doesn't open ports, but uses a cloud server instead.

Comment: how does an ipcamera connect to its cloud server ? I cannot see any other ports open. Please pardon my silly questions. I am very new to iot :|

Comment: that's not as much of an IoT question as it is a networking question. Devices making outbound connections don't "open ports" when doing so.

Comment: "What is UPnP used for?" This is very easy to look up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play

Comment: "Why is ipcam not setting up port forwarding on my router?" Because it doesn't need to have a remote server connect to *it*. It only needs to connect *out*. This is not a security question but a very basic networking question.

Answer (score 1):

It just opens an outbound connection to the server, like a regular user would to upload to youtube or stream to twitch.